# one item clickable in RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, onitemselectedlistener

i'm working on some kind of educational game, in this game i represent nine levels in recyclerview each level is enabled when the previous one, now i'm trying to make one item in the recycler View enable and the others unable, i been searching in youtube , and other websites, my question is how to do it?(note: i'm new in android studio so keep it simple as possible).

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ItemView> items;
private Context context;

public ListAdapter(List<ItemView> items , Context context){
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
           .inflate(R.layout.item_list , parent , false);






return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     ItemView i = items.get(position);



                 holder.setHeadText(i.getHead());
     holder.setScoreText(i.getScore());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView headText , scoreText;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        headText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.head);
        scoreText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.score);
    }

    public void setHeadText(String headText) {
        this.headText.setText(headText);
    }

    public void setScoreText(String scoreText) {
        this.scoreText.setText(scoreText);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please share your activity's code and your recycler-view's adapter code.  If you don't have an adapter and you don't know what I'm talking about, I would suggest you reading this article: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/. I would also suggest you to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puyiZKvxBa0 which shows how to handle an item click in a recyclerview.

Comment: this is my adapter code

Comment: why do you need the activity code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by

**Add a interface like this in your adapter class**

```
 public interface ItemClickListner{
    void onItemClick(ItemView item);
}
```

**Initialize this Interface**

```
    private ItemClickListner clickManager;
```

**Add a Param Adapter class constructor**

```
public ListAdapter(List<ItemView> items , Context context,ItemClickListner clickManager){
this.items = items;
this.context = context;
this.clickManager=clickManager;
}
```

**In Your ViewHolder Add a OnClickListner for itemView**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**in Your `onClick` override function**

```
if(clickManager!=null)
    clickManager.onItemClick(items.get(getAdapterPosition()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to implement the `onClick listener` for an item in your `adapter`, and getting the position of the clicked item. My goal in this case is making only the **fifth** view in the `Recyler-View` clickable.

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView headText , scoreText;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            headText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.head);
            scoreText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.score);
        }

   @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(getLayoutPosition()==5){
        //your code goes here...
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: after i put this i don't need to make new listener right?

Comment: @user8545027 What do you mean by "new listener"? This is the only listener you need for listening to all of the clicks in the recycler-view items.