# NULL Pointer Exception Error Application Crashed After Clicking on Recycler List Item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am working on an android application that is showing data in Recycle List View Holder. When I Click on List Item in Recycler View Holder the application crashes.

```
public class UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers.UserViewHolder> {

private List<User> listUsers;
Context mContext;
ItemClickListenerLongPressed itemClickListenerLongPressed;

public UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers(List<User> listUsers) {
    this.listUsers = listUsers;
}


@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_user_recycler_second, parent, false);

    return new UserViewHolder(itemView);
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textViewID.setText(listUsers.get(position).getUserid());
    holder.textViewName.setText(listUsers.get(position).getName());
    holder.textViewPassword.setText(listUsers.get(position).getPassword());
    holder.textViewRole.setText(listUsers.get(position).getRole());

}

public void setItemClickListenerLongPressed(ItemClickListenerLongPressed itemClickListenerLongPressed){
    this.itemClickListenerLongPressed=itemClickListenerLongPressed;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.v(UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers.class.getSimpleName(),""+listUsers.size());
    return listUsers.size();
}

/**
 * ViewHolder class
 */
public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    //public AppCompatTextView ID;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewID;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewName;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewPassword;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewRole;

    public UserViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        textViewID = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
        textViewName = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewPassword = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPassword);
        textViewRole = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewRole);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (itemClickListenerLongPressed != null) itemClickListenerLongPressed.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "USMAN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

}

Here is the users List activity

```
public class UsersListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemClickListenerLongPressed{

AppCompatActivity activity = UsersListActivity.this;

AppCompatTextView textViewName;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
AppCompatButton textViewButtonNewUser;
UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers userRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers;
List<User> listUsers;

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_record_updated_list);
    mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewUsers);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(userRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers);
    userRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers.setItemClickListenerLongPressed(this);

    initViews();
    initObjects();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(UsersListActivity.this,AdminMain.class));
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}


/**
 * This method is to initialize views
 */
private void initViews() {
    textViewName = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    textViewButtonNewUser = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.btnaddnew);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewUsers);
    textViewButtonNewUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(UsersListActivity.this,UserRecordSaveActivity.class));
        }
    });

}

/**
 * This method is to initialize objects to be used
 */
private void initObjects() {
    listUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    userRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers = new UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers(listUsers);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(userRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);

    String emailFromIntent = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERS");
    textViewName.setText(emailFromIntent);

    getDataFromSQLite();
}

/**
 * This method is to fetch all user records from SQLite
 */
private void getDataFromSQLite() {
    // AsyncTask is used that SQLite operation not blocks the UI Thread.
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            listUsers.clear();
            listUsers.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllUser());

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            userRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {

}
```

}

When I clicked on the List Item it crashed and the error was caused by Toast. As I remove the toast the Error goes because of using a try catch item not clicked.

Here is the image of Error.

After Removing try catch It again shows error but this time the error is shown on AlertDialog. Builder.  Here is the image of error without try catch.

[Image after removing try and catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65zkU.png)

[ERROR BEFORE REMOVING TOAST OVER ON CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eOXK.png)

Image after adding toast logcat Error
[Image After Adding Toast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO9rf.)

The error is now on users list activity
[Image after eidting of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1USeh.png)

The actual data in list when removing the click listener
[Actual data in list by removing the click listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO2p0.png)

Here is my recycler layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/Indigo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="User ID"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="User ID"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/hint_password"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/hint_password"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Role"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRole"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Role"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Image of Logcat

[Logcat Image at Updating Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUtjp.png)

Here is the IMEIRecord Save activity Adapter like user record..

```
public class IMEIRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IMEIRecyclerAdapter.ImeiViewHolder> {

private List<User> ListImei;
Context mContext;
ItemClickListenerLongPressed itemClickListenerLongPressed;
View itemView;

public IMEIRecyclerAdapter(List<User> ListImei) {
    this.ListImei = ListImei;
}


@Override
public ImeiViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_user_recycler_imei, parent, false);

    return new ImeiViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImeiViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final User user= ListImei.get(position);
    holder.textViewImeiId.setText(ListImei.get(position).getImeiid());
     holder.textViewImeiNo.setText(ListImei.get(position).getImei());
}

public void setItemClickListenerLongPressed(ItemClickListenerLongPressed itemClickListenerLongPressed) {
    this.itemClickListenerLongPressed = itemClickListenerLongPressed;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.v(UsersRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(),""+ListImei.size());
    return ListImei.size();
}

public void displayingAlertDialogimei() {
    final User user= new User();
    //displaying alert dialog box
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(itemView.getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Choose Option");
    builder.setMessage("Update or Delete?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //go to update activity
            goToUpdateActivity(user.getUserid());
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //go to update activity
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert11 = builder.create();
    alert11.show();
}

private void goToUpdateActivity(String userid) {
    Intent goToUpdate = new Intent(mContext, RoughUser.class);
    goToUpdate.putExtra("USER_ID", userid);
    mContext.startActivity(goToUpdate);

}


public class ImeiViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public AppCompatTextView textViewImeiId;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewImeiNo;
    LinearLayout layout;


    public ImeiViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        textViewImeiId = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewImeiId);
        textViewImeiNo = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewImeiNo);
        layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view_imei);

        layout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        displayingAlertDialogimei();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: AlertDialog needs a ThemedContext. The easiest was to get that, is to pass an activity instead of the context!

Comment: It's not "instead". Activity is Context subclass.

Comment: Then how to resolve this

Comment: I am unable to pass an activity to this

Comment: It does not allows me to pass the activity over onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add **id** to your parent LinearLayout  as, **android:id="@+id/list_view"**

and then update adapter class

```
public class UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers.UserViewHolder> {

private List<User> listUsers;
Context mContext;
ItemClickListenerLongPressed itemClickListenerLongPressed;
View itemView;

public UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers(List<User> listUsers) {
this.listUsers = listUsers;
}


@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)       {
itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item_user_recycler_second, parent, false);

return new UserViewHolder(itemView);
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.textViewID.setText(listUsers.get(position).getUserid());
holder.textViewName.setText(listUsers.get(position).getName());
holder.textViewPassword.setText(listUsers.get(position).getPassword());
holder.textViewRole.setText(listUsers.get(position).getRole());

}

public void setItemClickListenerLongPressed(ItemClickListenerLongPressed itemClickListenerLongPressed){
this.itemClickListenerLongPressed=itemClickListenerLongPressed;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return listUsers.size();
}

private void displayingAlertDialog() {
    //displaying alert dialog box
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(itemView.getContext());
    builder.setMessage("your toast message here...");
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    builder.setPositiveButton(
            "Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });

    AlertDialog alert11 = builder.create();
    alert11.show();
}

/**
 * ViewHolder class
 */
public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

//public AppCompatTextView ID;
public AppCompatTextView textViewID;
public AppCompatTextView textViewName;
public AppCompatTextView textViewPassword;
public AppCompatTextView textViewRole;
LinearLayout layout;

public UserViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);

    textViewID = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
    textViewName = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    textViewPassword = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPassword);
    textViewRole = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewRole);
    layout = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    layout.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    displayingAlertDialog();
}
}
```

Comment: It also give the same error this time over this toast

Comment: make global inflated view i.e.  itemView  and then try it may work

Comment: can you please add full logcat of error due to toast

Comment: I have just added

Comment: use this global view to get context in Toast

Comment: Ok I am trying to do that I will again post here if new sort of problem accur again

Comment: I have followed a tutorial to do this but after following that It remains the same issue, but this time on the users list activity.

Comment: can u add issue displayed in logcat

Comment: there is one thing to do...do not display Toast, Display AlertDialog..i m updating my code

Comment: i am using sqlite database for saving that data

Comment: upload your "item_user_recycler_second "layout file code

Comment: I have added layout file

Comment: now u can try updated code..if any error occurs please add logcat

Comment: I have the another same activity like this, where I show two textviews in recycler list, I have make changes to that one like this but that also make a same error on alert dialog

Comment: I have matched all of the code but no difference remains, but when this runs it make a crash

Comment: In this scenario dialog box open and when I try to add some action over it It crashes with null pointer exception like before

Answer (score 1):

You have not declare `mContext` in your adapter class.
In Adapter class constructor may change like this.

```
public UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers(List<User> listUsers,Context context) {
    this.mContext= context;
    this.listUsers1 = listUsers;
    user= new User();
}
```

and Recycle view Activity class you have to change

```
UserRecyclerAdapterSavedUsers myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(yourList,this);
```

Comment: The Error is still the same after adding this

Comment: please add your stack trace

Comment: The Error Remains the same

Comment: I have added the getitemcount under the onclick it shows me the number of items when i click on the list

Comment: but when I add a toast or something else under on click it shows the same error again

Answer (score 0):

Use the Recyclerview Item click like this [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335280/one-item-clickable-in-recyclerview-in-android/49336197#49336197)

and then you can access the interface in your `activity` or `fragment` and then you can add whatever you need.

- giving `toast` and populating `AlertDialog` inside the `Adapter`is not the  proper way of coding

Comment: I am trying to do that

Comment: I have followed a tutorial to do this but after following that It remains the same issue, but this time on the users list activity.